# How to call POST controller instead of GET method on form submit in mvc 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having problem on calling my POSt controller method on form submit. below are my two methods

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
{

}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult List(SearchTerms search,int page = 1)
{

}
```

On http request, my GET Method is called as i wanted. However, when i submit my form, i am expecting the POST method to be called, yet the same GET method is called again. The post method is never called. Please where do i go wrong? Any hel is appreciated. Below is my form.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Search",  
         FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-group text-right" }))
{
......
<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="addressSearch"  onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("List", "Search")'">Search</button>
</span>
...
}
```

Comment: the button have to be type=submit, i think. With type="button" you make GET request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your button does not submit the form. It redirect to the List page back, which makes the browser send a GET request. You can make the button submit the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("List", "Search",  
         FormMethod.Post, new { @class="form-group text-right" }))
{
......
<span class="input-group-btn">
   <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="addressSearch">Search</button>
</span>
...
}
```